# This permissions state confuses me

Tags: windows, file-permissions

```
(Administrator: Command Prompt)
E:\dev\Connect>d:\cygwin64\bin\sh
$ PATH=/bin:$PATH
$ ls -l UnarchiveAllPatients
total 25
drwxr-x---+ 1 jhudson Domain Users   0 Dec  1 13:06 Bin
-rwxr-x---+ 1 jhudson Domain Users 297 Dec  1 12:25 UnarchiveAllPatients.vbproj.user
drwxr-x---+ 1 jhudson Domain Users   0 Dec  1 13:06 obj
$ cd UnarchiveAllPatients
$ ls
Bin  UnarchiveAllPatients.vbproj.user  obj
$ exit

E:\dev\Connect>cd UnarchiveAllPatients
Access is denied.

E:\dev\Connect>
```

I don't get it. `sh` can cd to the directory and act like it's in the directory but `cmd` cannot.

This is the result of an `rsync` command taking nightly backups.

The output of `cacls` seems wrong to me:

```
E:\dev\Connect>cacls UnarchiveAllPatients
E:\dev\Connect\UnarchiveAllPatients NULL SID:(DENY)(special access:)
                                             READ_CONTROL
                                             FILE_READ_EA
                                             FILE_WRITE_EA
                                             FILE_EXECUTE
                                             FILE_DELETE_CHILD

                                    DEXTER2\jhudson:(DENY)(special access:)
                                                    FILE_READ_DATA
                                                    FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                                    FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                                    FILE_READ_EA
                                                    FILE_WRITE_EA
                                                    FILE_EXECUTE
                                                    FILE_DELETE_CHILD

                                    NULL SID:(OI)(CI)(IO)(DENY)(special access:)
                                                         READ_CONTROL
                                                         FILE_READ_EA
                                                         FILE_EXECUTE
                                                         FILE_DELETE_CHILD

                                    DEXTER2\jhudson:(special access:)
                                                    STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL
                                                    DELETE
                                                    READ_CONTROL
                                                    WRITE_DAC
                                                    WRITE_OWNER
                                                    SYNCHRONIZE
                                                    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
                                                    FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                                    FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

                                    DEXTER2\Domain Users:(special access:)
                                                         READ_CONTROL
                                                         SYNCHRONIZE
                                                         FILE_GENERIC_READ
                                                         FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
                                                         FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
                                                         FILE_READ_DATA
                                                         FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                                         FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                                         FILE_READ_EA
                                                         FILE_WRITE_EA
                                                         FILE_EXECUTE
                                                         FILE_DELETE_CHILD
                                                         FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                                         FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

                                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(special access:)
                                                        READ_CONTROL
                                                        SYNCHRONIZE
                                                        FILE_GENERIC_READ
                                                        FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
                                                        FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
                                                        FILE_READ_DATA
                                                        FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                                        FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                                        FILE_READ_EA
                                                        FILE_WRITE_EA
                                                        FILE_EXECUTE
                                                        FILE_DELETE_CHILD
                                                        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                                        FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

                                    BUILTIN\Administrators:(special access:)
                                                           READ_CONTROL
                                                           SYNCHRONIZE
                                                           FILE_GENERIC_READ
                                                           FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
                                                           FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
                                                           FILE_READ_DATA
                                                           FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                                           FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                                           FILE_READ_EA
                                                           FILE_WRITE_EA
                                                           FILE_EXECUTE
                                                           FILE_DELETE_CHILD
                                                           FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                                           FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

                                    Everyone:(special access:)
                                             READ_CONTROL
                                             SYNCHRONIZE
                                             FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES

                                    CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
                                    CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)R
                                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(special access:)
                                                                    READ_CONTROL
                                                                    SYNCHRONIZE
                                                                    FILE_GENERIC_READ
                                                                    FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
                                                                    FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
                                                                    FILE_READ_DATA
                                                                    FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                                                    FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                                                    FILE_READ_EA
                                                                    FILE_WRITE_EA
                                                                    FILE_EXECUTE
                                                                    FILE_DELETE_CHILD
                                                                    FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                                                    FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

                                    BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(special access:)
                                                                       READ_CONTROL
                                                                       SYNCHRONIZE
                                                                       FILE_GENERIC_READ
                                                                       FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
                                                                       FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
                                                                       FILE_READ_DATA
                                                                       FILE_WRITE_DATA
                                                                       FILE_APPEND_DATA
                                                                       FILE_READ_EA
                                                                       FILE_WRITE_EA
                                                                       FILE_EXECUTE
                                                                       FILE_DELETE_CHILD
                                                                       FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
                                                                       FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES

                                    Everyone:(OI)(CI)(IO)R
                                    DEXTER2\jhudson:(OI)(CI)F
```

icacls output:

```
E:\dev\Connect>icacls UnarchiveAllPatients
UnarchiveAllPatients NULL SID:(DENY)(Rc,REA,WEA,X,DC)
                     DEXTER2\jhudson:(DENY)(RD,WD,AD,REA,WEA,X,DC)
                     NULL SID:(OI)(CI)(IO)(DENY)(Rc,REA,X,DC)
                     DEXTER2\jhudson:(D,Rc,WDAC,WO,RA,WA)
                     DEXTER2\Domain Users:(RX,W,DC)
                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX,W,DC)
                     BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX,W,DC)
                     Everyone:(Rc,S,RA)
                     CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                     CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX)
                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                     BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX,W,DC)
                     Everyone:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX)
                     DEXTER2\jhudson:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

Comment: Can you show the `icacls` output for it?

Comment: @u1686_grawity: `icalcs` doesn't seem to be shipped anymore. I just get the not fond error message.

Comment: What OS are you running? It's still present in Windows 11 out of the box (it's the new tool; cacls is the old XP one). Are you sure you didn't mistype the command?

Comment: (Though, the ACL looks very much like a Cygwin attempt to translate the POSIX modes/ACLs to Windows ones; keeping in mind that Windows ACLs are additive while POSIX file permissions are not, so the mere absence of a POSIX permission bit _has to_ be represented as an explicit denial in Windows ACLs.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity: Yup typo'd icacls, twice.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you a local Admin? Does `whoami /priv` show SeRestorePrivilege available?

Comment: @u1686_grawity: I am, as shown at the top of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACL shows you as being denied most basic permissions on the directory, such as `FILE_READ_DATA` (which lets you list contents, much like +r on Linux). Cmd requests this permission when accessing the directory that you're cd'ing to, which fails because of the denial.

Cygwin, however, enables the `SeBackupPrivilege` and `SeRestorePrivilege` privilege bits whenever you're running as an administrator. These privileges allow you to *bypass* most ACL checks; much like being root (CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE) on Linux, only they're kept "held but inactive" by default on Windows, as opposed to root always having them active on Linux.

```c
523   /* Setting these rights at process startup allows processes running under
524      user tokens which are in the administrstors group to have root-like
525      permissions. */
526   /* Allow to access all files, independent of their ACL settings. */
527   set_privilege (token, SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE, true);
528   set_privilege (token, SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE, true);
```

As a result of that, any Cygwin-based process becomes able to access files that normal Windows programs cannot. (You can do the same in PowerShell using the PSPrivilege module from PSGallery.)

Do not use rsync to back up Windows files; it will not preserve the ACLs correctly – use robocopy.

(No, I don't know why Cygwin shows you as having `rwx` when the ACL says otherwise.)

---

(Another denied permission, `FILE_EXECUTE` also technically has the same "enter directory" meaning on Windows as +x on Linux; it just happens that modern Windows versions ignore it.)